# mutual_info_classif will not run with a large number of variables

Tags: scikit-learn

I am attempting to set up a process to use a number of different feature selection methods on two datasets. One of which is mutual_info_classif(). Both have ~1K samples.

The first data set consists of rna expression data and has ~60K variables.

The second data set consists of methylation array data and has ~300K variables.

I can run the mutual_info_classif on the rna dataset with ~60K variables. It takes a fairly long time, but as I understand it, mutual information calculations are quite intensive, so I'm fine with that.

When I attempt to run on the mutual information dataset, the script borks, usually comparatively quickly, within a minute or so.

I'm using the following code for both datasets (swapping out the data file obviously).

```
import anndata as ad
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif, SelectKBest

methylationData = ad.read("methylationHG38.h5ad")

selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k=1000)
selector.fit(adata.X, adata.obs.final_diagnosis)
```

When it does fall over, it provides no error messages, it just dies.

It will run smaller subsets of the larger dataset, so the only thing that I can think of, is that it might be a resource issue? It's running on an Ubunutu vm with 32G of memory and 16 cores, so I'm wondering if it's a case of insufficient memory, and the system is killing it, but I don't really know how to confirm that without error messages.

I have (in theory) no problem with it taking ages to run. Though if it scales linearly with the number of variables, it'll end up taking a few days. At some point I'll have to look for a solution to that, but for now I just want the thing to run. If I need to spin up a bigger machine, that is an option.

Theories as to what is happening, or where I might look to figure out what's going on, would be much appreciated.